# PC Driver for Roland TD-1DMK

Tags: drums, electronic-drumset

I recently bought a Roland TD-1DMK kit.

I want to connect it with my laptop. But when I go to the Roland site, I can find drivers for TD-11, but not for TD-1.

Where can I find the drivers for TD-1?

Comment: What do you expect the driver to do? The drum kit is just a USB MIDI device and shouldn't need specific drivers.

Comment: @ojs Ok. I thought the drivers are kit specific, as is generally the case with any other hardware.